# How to prevent from out touch in window manager?

Tags: android

I have a service from which I want to show a layout using a window manager which I successfully implemented but I need to do 2 things I want to access a button in layout and prevent from outside touch. How do I do that

```
 final WindowManager windowManager=(WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet,null);
        cancel = layout.findViewById(R.id.img_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(layout);
            }
        });
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);


        p.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

        windowManager.addView(layout,p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these flags

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O ? LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY : LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

Override `onTouchEvent()` of dialog

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {  

   if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  
    System.out.println("TOuch outside the dialog ******************** ");  

   }  
   return false;  
 }
```

Comment: this is not a dialog its a window manager opening from service

Comment: The above code is not working. How did you override onTouchEvent() of dialog?